# iphone device Testing errors?

Tags: testing, iphone-sdk-3.0, device

I'm currently trying to test my iPhone application on a real device but I have multiple errors like that:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITableView", referenced from:
   __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in CustomSearchController.o
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in HistoryController.o
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in SavedSearchesController.o
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in FiltersController.o
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in LoadSearch.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableDictionary", referenced from:
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in SBJsonParser.o
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in audioController.o
"_NSHomeDirectory", referenced from:
  -[audioController record] in audioController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
  __objc_classrefs__DATA@0 in audioController.o
"___objc_personality_v0", referenced from:
  ___objc_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in SearchSingleton.o
```

I don't know how to solve that, I think I configure my project the good way, is it a problem of frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by drag n drop the frameworks in my project instead of right click on the frameworks folder -> add existing framework